# does declaring a variable as private show any difference from declaring it as final while inheritance

Tags: java, access-specifier

**EDIT: sorry for the inconvenience, it was lack of understanding of the concept. u can simply ignore this question.**

i am pretty sure that we can't inherit neither final nor private variables. but,  why should we declare variables as final when declaring them as private can stop them from inheriting.

i even know that the value of final variables can not be changed neither by a base class or derived class. what i want to infer is whether declaring a variable as private or final really show any difference while inheriting.

PS: I could not get clarification anywhere from the internet. each source explaining them separately even though both of them show almost same behaviour while inheriting them.

Comment: You don't need "the internet" to give you an answer: declare a class with a private field and a final field; then declare a subclass, and look at which of the two fields are inherited.

Comment: `private` and `final` are 2 completly different things, accessabilty and writeability. So making a variable private indicates it is only used in that exact class. Whereas making it final just sets it to readonly. TBH I don't understand your question

Answer (score 3):

> i am pretty sure that we can't inherit neither final nor private variables

This is true for `private` fields, not for `final` fields. Final fields **are** inherited (non-private ones, that is). Whether they can be modified or not has nothing to do with inheritance.

With regards to inheritance, `final` has significance when it comes to inherited **methods** (a `final` method cannot be overridden) and classes' ability to be inherited (a `final` class cannot be extended).

> why should we declare variables as final when declaring them as private can stop them from inheriting.

You declare a variable as `final` for a different reason. `private` encapsulates the field, whereas `final` makes it impossible to reassign.